I am trying to store blogs that users have marked as favorite locally on their devices. Which method should I use, Shared preferences or Sqflite?
So I was trying to store favorite blogs on user's device locally instead of uploading to a sever. I know Shared preferences is not recommended to be used for a large size data but for the above scenario, Is it okay to use Shared preferences over sqflite, or should I stick with sqflite?

shared pref is fairly limited space and complexity.    do you expect the data to get large or complex?

Its just static Map<String, dynamic> with 3-4 props. But I don't know how many favorite blogs a user may have.

sqflite is pretty simple if you know SQL.  I'd suggest using that.

Using sqflite would give you the benefits of having table storage: being able to sort entries by name, time created, etc.
